# Trouble with javascript if statement

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Ok, I'm making a login and registration panel with jquery and php.  In short, if there are errors with the registration it sets a few form errors, redirects back to the registration page, the javascript detects there are errors with the use of a php variable and forces the slider to show itself.

The working code: Above the doc type `$errors = $form->num_errors;` and the whole `$errors` routine works fine.

My problem is that I also have a verification that the form was submitted successfully.  It uses

```
if(isset($_SESSION['regsuccess'])){
    $success = 1;
} else {
    $success = 0;
}
```

to set the `$success` variable.  The crazy thing here is that this doesn't work using the same routine as the `$error` variable.  I know the `$success` conditional is working correctly as I have an it echoed out further down the page.

jQuery slide script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var num_errors = "<?php $errors; ?>";
    var form_success = "<?php $success; ?>";

    // Expand Panel
    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
    });
    // Collapse Panel
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideUp("slow"); 
    });     

    // Switch buttons from "Log In | Register" to "Close Panel" on click
    $("#toggle a").click(function () {
        $("#toggle a").toggle();
    });      

    //this part works
    if(errors>0){
        $("div#panel").slideDown();
        $("#toggle a").toggle();
    }

        //this part doesn't
    if(form_success>0){
        $("div#panel").slideDown();
        $("#toggle a").toggle();        
    }

});
```

The demo page is here `http://demo.ivannovak.com/danlogin/index.php`

Suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your page, you have an `errors` variable defined, that's why that portion works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
<!--
errors = 0; // -->
</script>
```

Your javascript file isn't processed by php, it's served directly by the web server so your variables in what you listed above:

```
var num_errors = "<?php $errors; ?>";
var form_success = "<?php $success; ?>";
```

Those come out exactly that way to the client, they aren't replaced with their values.  You need to move those 2 lines into your page where you have errors now, and remove them from quotes as well.  Take them out of your js and use this in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
  var num_errors = <?php $errors; ?>;
  var form_success = <?php $success; ?>;
</script>
```